# SQLite Insert or Ignore/Replace with lastInsertID in one statement

Tags: sqlite, pdo

I feel like this should be easy...

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name COLLATE NOCASE)
)
```

No two names are the same, case insensitive.  Right now I have users adding names and it does this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES ("my name");
```

And I need to get the id of the row, which is easy with PHP PDO's lastInsertID().  But I also want, if the user is adding a name that's already in the database, for nothing to be added to the database, but still get that id without having to do another database call.  I was hoping for something like

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (name) VALUES ("my name");
```

And have it just overwrite the same data into the cell and return the lastInsertID (even though it wasn't inserted?).  But that doesn't work.  What are my other options?  Will I have to do a separate database query to see if the `name` field already exists?

Answer (score 0):

With the OR REPLACE clause, the statement always *deletes* any old row.

Just use two statements. (There is no technical reason for doing this in a single statement.)